# Overfull hbox in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking, warnings

I just ran into a problem using biblatex with a long author and title: The output extends past the right margin of my text, because biblatex does not insert a linebreak before the date. Please see the picture below for what exactly I am talking about.

[image: Overfull hbox]

The black box is because of the drafts option; although you can't really see that the text is longer than the other lines, this is clearly visible when I add other references (this is a minimal example). As you can see, I am using babel with ngerman, without this package, the date (`Mar. 19, 2014`) works fine without overfull hboxes.

This is the code for the output above:

```
\documentclass[draft, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@ONLINE{first,
  author = {Das ist der erste Autor},
  title = {Viel zu lange Quellenangabe im Literaturverzeichnis},
  date = "2014-03-19"
}
@ONLINE{second,
  author = {Other Author},
  title = {Reference},
  date = "2014-03-19"
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={40mm, 20mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\begin{document}
\cite{first}\cite{second}
{\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\small}
\printbibliography
}
\end{document} % <-- this is line 23
```

Biblatex reports this warning:

```
Overfull \hbox (0.29396pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 23--23
[]\T1/ntxrx/m/n/10.95 Das ist der ers-te Au-tor. \T1/ntxrx/m/it/10.95 Viel zu lan-ge Quel-len-an-ga-be im Li-te-ra-tur-ver-zeich-nis\T1/ntxrx/m/n/10.95 . 19. März|
 []
```

I already tried using various options on biblatex and including `microtype`, but none of them worked. I can't change the font, size and margins.

This problem only occurs when I also cite a second reference, therefore I included two of them in my MWE.

Do you have any ideas how to make biblatex either include a linebreak before the date or adjust the line in another way so that the text no longer extends past the right margin?

Comment: I doubt that 0.29pt is really visible. Apart from this: add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[final]{microtype}` (the final is there to overwrite your global draft).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer this is just a minimal example, in the real document, it is about 1.6pt and it is visible in the printed version as well. But lockstep's answer already solved my problem.

Comment: I wouldn't add the emergencystretch globally but only before the bibliography.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you very much!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Add the following to your preamble:

```
\emergencystretch=1em
```

This allows for an additional line-breaking pass with the amount of "tolerable" white space per line increased by 1em.

Alternatively, and as suggested by Ulrike Fischer, load the `microtype` package with the `final` package option to ensure that the microtypographic features are activated even when using the `draft` class option.

Both methods will cause the warning in your example to disappear.

Comment: I think you just saved my PhD.

Comment: I think `\emergencystretch` can appear anywhere, not only in the preamble.

Comment: This reduced my warnings from 3 to only 1 overfull hbox. Then I tried 2em, which only made everything worse. Finally, instead of `\emergencystretch`, I simply added `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the preamble and all warnings went away. All my bad boxes were overfull by less than 1 pt.

Comment: Notice: Increasing the value of `\emergencystretch` can make things worse as stopping latex from hyphenating words and just stretching everything: [Why my document is not hyphenating on words starting with upper case letter? (I am not using \uchyph=0)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499457)