# What is the type of citition for J.UCS journal?

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, msword, markup

Please I need to know the type of citation for references for Journal of Universal Computer science, they don't provide the citation type at this [guide](http://www.jucs.org/ujs/jucs/info/submissions/style_guide.html#ID_0x00000000_0x000103f1).

How can I automatically add my references if I used their format in word version?

Example (referencing Journals:):

> [Wonko and Tsio 99b] Wonko, A. C., Tsio, F.: "Extended Use of Hyperlinks"; J.UCS (Journal for Universal Computer
>   Science), 5, 3 (1999), 225-327. The form 5, 3 (1999) indicates volume
>   number 5, issue number 3 1999. 225-327 indicate the page numbering.

Answer (score 1):

H. Today I found the same trouble with the template that provides the website of the JUCS. After many tests, the appropriate solution was to install the package "apalike". Interestingly, the first test was on the template that JUCS provides to work and the format of the references was not in the appropriate format such as the journal requires. However, I did a simple document with one citation and I compile the document, the editor ask me for install the package "apalike", I clicked yes, the result was successfully. So, I did the same on the template and I a got it.

**Example of the code:**

My citation....

```
\cite{Alemdar2015}
```

The last paragraph in the template

```
\section{Conclusions and Future Work}
```

Until recently, focus in metadata research has focused on what
metadata is and how it should be represented to the user...

the bibliography section with parameters

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike} %the style for JUCS
\bibliography{mybib} % the file containing my bibliography
```

The original bibliography of the template (commented)

```
%\begin{thebibliography}{5}
%
%\bibitem[Anderson and Reich 2000]{sc2-proc} Anderson, K., Reich,
%S. (eds.): ``Proceedings of the Second Workshop on Structural
%Computing''; Lect. Notes Comp. Sci. 1903, Springer, Berlin.
%
%\bibitem[Christodoulakis et~al. 1999]{callimachus} Christodoulakis,
```

[image]

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

`\bibliographystyle{apalike}` may not be the right choice for J.UCS as it doesn't break refs properly (i.e., they are frequently sticking out of text bounds, i.e., lots of overfull hboxes).

A **partial solution** is to use this in the preamble (fixes most overfull hboxes but not all):

```
\emergencystretch=1em
```

The **full solution** is to use this package:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

... cite with `\citep` instead of `\cite`:

```
\citep{Author2019}
```

... and use this bibliography style:

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

See also:

- [Line breaking (or hyphenation?) of references in apalike](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437/line-breaking-or-hyphenation-of-references-in-apalike)
- [Overfull hbox in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171999/overfull-hbox-in-biblatex)