# Overfull \hbox is too wide

Tags: errors

I'm trying to compile my tex file but it keeps giving me this error.

```
Overfull \hbox (11.0894pt too wide)
```

Someone who can help me out?

Comment: This is not technically an error: It's just telling you that LaTeX didn't find a good way to break your lines nicely and so now a line runs into the margin. You first need to find the line that causes this message. There should be a line number in the warning. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35/35864

Comment: I've found it :) this helped me https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171999/overfull-hbox-in-biblatex